# Padding-left around table not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, padding

I have a table embedded in a div, with an image floated to the left of it. I use padding-left to add some space between the image and the table. It works as I want in most browsers, but in IE7, the table is touching the image. When I inspect the element, the padding is overlapping the table instead of going to the left of it.

I tried replicating this in a minimal fiddle, but my attempt ran into this misbehavior in all browsers, so I'm not sure what's different on the real page.

The real page is:

http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/lessons/index-so.php?cat_id=3

The spacing I'm concerned with is to the left of "Title:".

The attempted fiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/HaCgF/4/

How can I get this spacing consistently in all browsers?

Comment: Try floating the table container left: `.movie_data { float: left; }` and clearing the movie container; `.movie { overflow: auto }`. I don't have IE7 available right now, so I'm guessing here :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `padding-left` on the table, try adding a `margin-right` on the image. See the very minor change I made to [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufAZW/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to remove padding on table, and put margin-left on image?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/HaCgF/6/) at an answer. I moved a bit around (yell at me if it was too much :-p)… applied a clearfix to the `.movie` elements, etc. This is how I would do it. I moved the padding to the image instead of the `TABLE`. I've noticed padding on tables isn't always what you expect it to be, and I think most browsers only really expect padding on the inside of `TH` and `TD` elements.